# ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3) List Python

Tags: python-3.x, arraylist

I have this code

```
car = list()
model = list()
year = list()
for cars in self.browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//td[@data-field="action_id"]'):
    car.append(cars.text)

for models in self.browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//td[@data-field="task_id"]'):
    model.append(models.text)

for years in self.browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//td[@data-field="processo"]'):
    year.append(years.text)

for x, y, z in car, model, year:
    print(x, y, z)
```

I remove the text from each column to put it in a list and then read those 3 lists in an organized way

example page

```
Car           Model    Year
____          _____    ____
BMW           350i     2000
Chevrolet     Cruze    2018
Ford          Mustang  2017
```

the return I am wanting to make

```
car model year
car model year
car model year
```

but this error returns to me

> ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)

this is just an example similar to the site i'm working on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use itertools to iterate with multiple variables

```
import itertools
#itertools.izip runs till one of the lists is exhausted
for (x, y, z) in itertools.izip(car, model, year):
   print(x, y, z)
#or 
for (x, y, z) in itertools.izip_longest(car, model, year):
   print(x ,y ,z)
#itertools.izip_longest tuns till the longest list is exhausted
#or 
for x, y, z in zip(car, model, year):
  print(x, y, z)
```

you can use either zip or izip but izip is better because zip computes all the list at once, izip computes the elements only when requested.